# Property and Field in Java way

Tags: java, computer-science

Is it correct to assume that Property in Java it is simple getter and setter?

Comment: Most adhere to the [JavaBean standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans) -- `public void setSecret(String secret)`, and `public String getSecret()`

Comment: Yes, I know it. But what is property here? A `method`?

Comment: Are you asking how to define a property in C#? Or how to write a C# property like a Java one?

Comment: No. I'm asking about property in Java.

Comment: Tag's been removed. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, a Java property is a private field with a getter/setter pair.

Comment: Are you sure about that?

Comment: Have been answer on here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70471/no-properties-in-java

Comment: may it will help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10115588/what-is-the-difference-between-field-variable-attribute-and-property-in-java

Answer (score 3):

As @Hovercraft Full of Eels mentioned, standard Java Beans appear to have properties (provided by getter and setter methods), but Properties do not exist in Java as they exist in C# (see question [No Properties in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70471/no-properties-in-java))

Answer (score 0):

In your example there are just a field named `secret` and two methods named `property`.

You can have two methods with the same name in java because this language supports polymorphism.

There is an important condition, the two methods can have the same name but not the same signature, parameters and/or return type should be differents.

You can find more information about polymorphism in java here : [polymorphism in java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html)

Comment: My question is not about polymorphism. It's about properties in Java as part of language.

Comment: Ok, so the best answer is eurythmia's one :  Properties do not exist in Java as they exist in C#